# How do I call the procedure section from window application using asynchronous method on progress 4GL?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I want to use Asynchronous method but the problem is when I write a query like below then program read only main block and definition section and it's not entered into procedure section. I want to read that too.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE hAsynCall     AS HANDLE      NO-UNDO.

ASSIGN cPgmTest = Test.p

RUN VALUE(cPgmTest) ON SERVER gshAstraAppserver ASYNCHRONOUS
    SET hAsynCall (INPUT 'Csv') NO-ERROR.
IF ERROR-STATUS:ERROR THEN DO:
   MESSAGE ERROR-STATUS:GET-MESSAGE(1).
END.


DO WHILE NOT hAsynCall :COMPLETE:

  PROCESS EVENTS.

  IF hAsynCall :COMPLETE THEN

    MESSAGE "completed"        
      VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFORMATION.

  ELSE /* Async result not ready, so do something else. */
    MESSAGE "Not yet ..." VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFORMATION.

END. 

/* Test.p*/

  /* Definition*/

  /*Main Block*/
    DEFINE INPUT PARAMETER cData AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
    PAUSE 5.

  /*Procedure*/

  /*Function*/
```

As you see above the program was read up to main block but if i cut the query from main block and paste into procedure block then its doesn't not entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run your AppServer procedure *persistently* and then run the asynchronous call in that.

https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dvref%2Frun-statement.html

Something like:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE hp AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.

RUN test.p PERSISTENT SET hp.
RUN whatever IN hp ASYNCRHONOUS SET hasync ( "csv" ).

FINALLY:
   DELETE OBJECT hp.
END FINALLY.
```

Note that this pattern incurs two additional AppServer calls, a proxy stub can be used to prevent this.